# C++: Help explaining behaviour of simple program

Tags: c++, cout, cin

I have the following program:

```
int a, b;
while (true)
{
    a = 0; b = 0;
    cout << "Enter input..." << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << "You entered:" << endl;
    cout << a << endl << b << endl;
}
```

Now the program works as expected when I provide
the expected numeric input (i.e. "10 20").
However, if I input some bogus input like "a b",
the program goes into an infinite loop w/ the following output:

Enter input...
You Entered:
0
0
Enter input...
You Entered:
0
0
...and so on

Can someone explain why/how this happens?

Comment: You're not checking if the read operation succeeded (and clearing if it didn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cin would need to be flushed ...

basically you failed to read "a b" as numbers and you come back around in the loop with the same condition.

but best practice should probably be to read into a string then parse from the string

Comment: To clarify, on the second (and all future) iterations of the loop, the input buffer still contains "a b" so the `cin` statement returns immediately (and fails).

Answer (score 1):

See this article:

[Basic Input/Output C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

> What happens in the example above if the user enters something else that cannot be interpreted as an integer? Well, in this case, the extraction operation fails. And this, by default, lets the program continue without setting a value for variable i

To stop this happening, you should be checking if the input received is in fact, an Integer.

As said above, maybe try something like stringstream instead and then parse the string.

Comment: As it happens, this was the article I was following when I wrote this code. I knew it said the program will continue, so I expected it to just loop around and ask me for input again. Didn't realize it holds the input in "cin" if the previous call fails... causing it to fail over/over again.